# Convert RGB human body to a pose template for human pose estimation

Tags: python, image-processing, deep-learning, pose-estimation

I have datasets with 9081 256x256 RGB images containing 5 peoples with three possible actions: forward/backward, wave hands, and forward bend.

Based on my application, I want to convert different human bodies into human pose template to achieve something like this:
[image: Transformation]

(web: https://reurl.cc/Y9LvRD)

Namely, I don't need too many features such as colors and face, which will affect my neural network.

May i have some suggestions? Any help is much appreciated:)

Some sample of my RGB images:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you share some of your sample RGB images?

Comment: "Human pose estimation" would be the right keyword. Also have a look at [this link](https://www.v7labs.com/blog/human-pose-estimation-guide)

Comment: If your goal is just to get the image on the right, you can just convert the image to grayscale and apply a binary threshold at a high value (250 for example if your background is white) and set the pixels below that to a gray value as the right image.

Comment: Hi, @Rahul Kedia, I upload some examples on my issue.

Comment: Hi, @Jeru Luke, thank you for your reply:) I will try to understand it.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT :This only works for the example that was shown in the original post, the edited post is much more challenging than that !

You can select the area that is not white and set it to gray this way :

```
import skimage.io
import numpy as np


img = skimage.io.imread('themaninred.png')
tol= 50 #tolerance for the whiteness of white
img[np.sum(img, axis = 2) <255*3-tol] = [128,128,128]

skimage.io.imsave('themaninredbutgray.png', img )
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply:) I use your code to test, but the result is poor. I have tried different tolerances but I can't get similar effect like you show.

Comment: This very simple approach assumes that the background is white ! I saw on your update that you have a background that is a lot messier than the first image you gave !

Comment: For the RGB images that you show, you will need to use some Deep Learning solutions

Comment: OK, I will find some methods. I use the first image as example because I can segment human from the background. But if I can use my datasets directly, it would be more suitable for my application.

Comment: Is your background always the same or do you move the camera ?

Comment: Yes, the background is same and camera is fixed in front of people. The detection range is 3~5 meters.